# In ruby, how do you write item.nil? ? nil : item.id.to_s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There has to be better way to write `item.nil? ? nil : item.id.to_s`. Anyone know it?

Comment: Maybe there's a better way to approach the problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `unless`:

```
item.id.to_s unless item.nil?
```

I case the condition is false, this expression evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: Curious. Why `unless` with an explicit call to `nil?` Just more obvious what's going on?

Comment: @O-I Rather to be more accurate as OP used it as well.

Comment: I'm a fan. This makes a lot of sense and I like the explicit .nil? as opposed to just item

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible :

```
   item && item.id.to_s
```

Example :

```
a = 23
a && a.to_s # => "23"
a = nil
a && a.to_s # => nil
```

Comment: With the third attempt …

Comment: @Gumbo Yes.. indeed.. :)

Comment: This may not work if `a` is falsely like `a = false`.

Comment: @Gumbo looking at the code, I am sure `item` is an object,as OP called method `id` on it. So no chance of `false` value, either `nil` or truth value.. ofcourse.

Comment: @ArupRakshit At least he *expects* `item` to be either `nil` or an object with `id`.

Comment: item is a RoR object loaded from the database, so I certainly hope it's not falsely.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like:

```
item.id.to_s if item
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if item evaluated to false, but I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have "ruby-on-rails tag", on rails you can do `item.try(:id).try(:to_s)`
Here's an example

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/try'
class Item
  attr_accessor :id
end

item= Item.new
item.id= 42
p item.try(:id).try(:to_s)
item= nil
p item.try(:id).try(:to_s)
```

> > "42"
> >
> > nil

Comment: I really like this one if you're using Rails. Still allows for method chaining. Nice, nurettin!

Comment: Awesome, did not know about the `try` method, thanks.

Comment: @kdeisz try method shines upon my code like a bright fire cleansing conditionals (+1 for drunkenness?)

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Not the best way by far, see below comments.

After the below monkey patch nil.id.to_s will start to return nil.

```
class NilClass
    def id
            self
    end
    def to_s
            self
    end
end
```

Comment: This seems hugely dangerous/absolutely horrible to test.

Comment: so nil.to_s starts returning nil instead of "" ?